# Post to Facebook automatically (onLoad) using OpenGraph API and JQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, web-applications, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to post automatically to a user's facebook timeline when the user submits a "stamp" on my website. I'm running a test script and the entire code is below.

You'll see the two methods i'm  using to test the script below:

- one listening for a click event on the class .openGraphButton
- and the other calls the postFB() function in a body onLoad event.

PROBLEM:

When the user clicks the "fb" button, the script works fine and posts to fb wall/timeline. However, when the page is loaded and tries to post via the onLoad call, I get the error message code.

GOAL:

I want to post to a user's facebook timeline automatically when the page loads (i.e. not having the user click the "fb" button). This way, when a user makes a new post (aka "stamp" on my website), the post/stamp will appear on facebook.

NOTES: I'm using the word "stamp" to refer to the user's post on my domain/website.

MY CODE:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="postFB(30,85)">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.openGraphButton').click(function(){
            var action = $(this).attr('action');
            var page = $(this).attr('page');
            var userid = 30;
            var stokeid = 85;
            postFB(userid,stokeid);
        });
    });

    function postFB(userid, stokeid){
        var url = "http://www.domain.com/profile-stoke.php?pid="+userid+"&sid="+stokeid;
        postAction ('stamp','passport',url);
    };

    function postAction( action, object_type, object_url ){
        FB.api('/me/[APP_NAME_SPACE]:stamp', 'post', { passport : object_url },function(response){
            if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Error occured' + action + '?' + object_type + '=' + object_url);
            } else {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
    }    
</script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//www.domain.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<input type="button" value="fb" class="openGraphButton" action="stamp" page="http://www.domain.com/profile-stoke.php?pid=30&sid=85" />
</body>
```

UPDATE:

Ok, so i get the error code 2500 with the message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.". However, when I click on the button, it works fine. I've tried implementing a jquery click event to mimic a click, but I get the same error. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help -- I appreciate it.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? and why are you including the SDK twice? Er, and why are you auto-posting on a GET request to a page? an action like that probably won't be approved by Facebook if it auto posts based on a page load or something like that

Comment: I don't know the error. The error is what is in my alert call alert('Error occured' + action + '?' + object_type + '=' + object_url). I don't know why i'm including it twice... probably because I didn't know I was... what code should I eliminate. Assuming: "<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>"

Comment: re: the GET request, it's because the user just added a new post to my database and the the get request (assuming you're referring to the URL) is the url of the recent post.

Comment: You only need one of the blocks with ` js.src =`

Comment: thanks, I removed one. Any thoughts on how I can implement the autopost?

Comment: After the init completes it should work according to the docs - what's the error in your console?

Comment: FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem

Comment: I removed the #xfbml info from the sdk and it solved this error. Igy, can you help me resolve the autopost issue?

Comment: Ok, so i get the error code 2500 with the message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.". However, when I click on the button, it works fine. I've tried implementing a jquery click event to mimic a click, but I get the same error. Any ideas?